# Passing space delimited string to stored procedure to search entire database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

How can I pass a string space delimited to a stored procedure and filter the result?

I'm trying to do this

```
parameter  value
__________________
@query     key1 key2 key 3
```

Then in the stored procedure, I want to first

1. find all the results with key1.
2. filter step 1 with key2.
3. filter step2 with key3.

Another example:

```
col1        |       col2            | col3
------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------
hello xyz   |   abc is my last name | and I'm a developer
hello xyz   |       null            | and I'm a developer
```

If I search for any following it should return for each?

1. "xyz developer" returns 2 rows
2. "xyz abc" returns 1 row
3. "abc developer"returns 1 row
4. "hello" returns 2 rows
5. "hello    developer" returns 2 rows
6. "xyz" returns 2 rows

I'm using SQL Server 2016. I tried to use `split_string` to split query string. But I don't know how to pass this to the stored procedure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is really an awful design.  You shouldn't have composite data -- that's really what you're talking about -- stored in one parameter.  Separate them into their own parameters.  Why would you make it difficult for yourself when a stored procedure has the ability to take multiple params?

Comment: I think you should consider a full text index.  That seems to have the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: @rory.ap string_split function in sql server 2016 will split my string space delimited, I did a join on split_string and tried to do a search. The other problem is, I'm doing left outer joins on 5 tables, which is causing performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full Text Index is the way to go, but this will return your results.

One caveat (that I can think of).  If your search **expression/pattern** contains a column name, that will generate a false-positive

```
Declare @YourTable table (col1 varchar(50),col2 varchar(50),col3 varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('hello xyz','abc is my last name','and I''m a developer'),
('hello xyz', null                ,'and I''m a developer')

Declare @Search varchar(max) =  'xyz abc'

Select A.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select FullString=(Select A.* FOR XML Raw)) B
 Where FullString like '%'+replace(@Search,' ','%')+'%'
```

Returns

```
col1        col2                col3
hello xyz   abc is my last name and I'm a developer
```

> **EDIT - Multi-Word / Any Order Search**

Try this not fully tested.  I can't imagine this being very efficient especially with larger tables and numerous key words

```
Declare @YourTable table (col1 varchar(50),col2 varchar(50),col3 varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('hello xyz','abc is my last name','and I''m a developer'),
('hello xyz', null                ,'and I''m a developer')

Declare @Search varchar(max) =  'developer xyz'


Select *
 From  (
        Select Distinct A.*
              ,Hits = sum(sign(charindex(C.Value,B.FullString))) over (partition by B.FullString)
              ,Req  = C.Req
         From  @YourTable A
         Cross Apply (Select FullString=(Select A.* FOR XML Raw)) B
         Join  (Select *,Req=sum(1) over () From String_Split(@Search,' ') ) C on charindex(C.Value,B.FullString)>0
       ) A
 Where Hits=Req
```

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c77123a71c810716b36d73a92ac714eb

Comment: If i'm going to search for developer, does it return 2 results ?

Comment: @ISHIDA Yes it does

Comment: @ISHIDA To be clear, it IS a pattern search, so "Developer XYZ" will return no records

Comment: @ISHIDA You can search dates, and numerics without any conversions

Comment: Is it possible to do search with mix and match of words, like developer xyz should return 2 results and 'last developer' should return 2 results.

Comment: @ISHIDA Give me a moment

Comment: @ISHIDA just changed the cross join to a join

Comment: @ISHIDA in your requirements #2 and #7 are NOT consistent

Comment: Thank you John, Got direction on implementing it.

Comment: @ISHIDA Happy to help.